# How to sort rows of custom array by a value?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array value that needs to be in this order

```
let daysOfWeekArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

and currently my array looks like this

```
let allData = [CustomObject(day:"Tuesday", startTime: "5:00"), CustomObject(day:"Sunday", startTime: "3:00")]
array.append(allData)
```

How do I get the array to sort by the day?

Sorry if this seems like an easy question, new to sorting arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up the index of the day in your reference array and sort by that index value

```
array.sort(by: { 
    (daysOfWeekArray.firstIndex(of: $0.day) ?? Int.max) < (daysOfWeekArray.firstIndex(of: $1.day) ?? Int.max)})
```

I use `Int.max` in case the day isn't found so that element gets sorted last.

On a side note, the array you are using for order can be gotten from the `Calendar` class from the property `weekDaySymbols` so the sorting could be done by using that property directly

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
array.sort(by: { 
    (calendar.weekdaySymbols.firstIndex(of: $0.day) ?? Int.max) < (calendar.weekdaySymbols.firstIndex(of: $1.day)  ?? Int.max)})
```

Of course you need to be sure you use the right locale for your calendar.

Comment: Sort is O(nLog(n)) and first index is O(n) so this whole thing is O(n^2)*log(n) which is pretty disasterous performance wise; fortunately there aren't many days of the week, but really you should use a dictionary instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe not the best solution, but looks like worked.

```swift
let daysOfWeekArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

struct CustomObject {
    var day: String
    var startTime: String
}

let allData = [CustomObject(day:"Tuesday", startTime: "5:00"), CustomObject(day:"Friday", startTime: "3:00"), CustomObject(day:"Sunday", startTime: "3:00"), CustomObject(day:"Monday", startTime: "3:00")]

let sorted = allData.sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
    let aIndex = daysOfWeekArray.firstIndex(of: a.day)!
    let bIndex = daysOfWeekArray.firstIndex(of: b.day)!
    if aIndex > bIndex {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
print(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change those strings to enum like that:

```
enum DayOfWeek {
    case sunday
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
    case thursday
    case friday
    case saturday

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .sunday:       return "Sunday"
        case .monday:       return "Monday"
        case .tuesday:      return "Tuesday"
        case .wednesday:    return "Wednesday"
        case .thursday:     return "Thursday"
        case .friday:       return "Friday"
        case .saturday:     return "Saturday"
        }
    }

    var dayInWeek: Int {
        switch self {
        case .sunday:       return 0
        case .monday:       return 1
        case .tuesday:      return 2
        case .wednesday:    return 3
        case .thursday:     return 4
        case .friday:       return 5
        case .saturday:     return 6
        }
   }

    static var all: [DayOfWeek] {
       return [.sunday, .monday, .tuesday, .wednesday, .thursday, .friday, .saturday] 
    }
}
struct CustomObject {
    let day: DayOfWeek
    let startTime: String
    // ....
}

let daysOfWeekArray = DayOfWeek.all

let allData = [CustomObject(day:.tuesday, startTime: "5:00"), CustomObject(day:.sunday, startTime: "3:00")]
var array: [CustomObject] = []
array.append(contentsOf: allData)
array = array.sorted { $0.day.dayInWeek < $1.day.dayInWeek }
print(array.map{$0.day.title})
```